# Use array variables in subsetting IF without specifying number of array variables

Tags: sas, datastep

In SAS, I have a few columns of dollar values and several other columns.  I don't care about a row of data if it has 0 values for all dollar values and I don't want these rows in the final data.  The columns that are dollar values are already in an array Fix_Missing.  I am in the data step.

So, for example, I could do:

```
IF Fix_Missing{1} NE 0 OR Fix_Missing{2} NE 0 OR Fix_Missing{3} NE 0;
```

However, the number of variables in the array may change and I want code that works no matter how many variables are in it.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most functions that accept uncounted lists of variables, you can use `of array[*]`.

```
if sum(of fix_missing[*]) > 0
```

for example would work assuming fix_missing cannot have negative values.  You can also use this with CATS, so for example:

```
if cats(of fix_missing[*]) ne '000';
```

would work, and you could do something even like this:

```
if cats(of fix_missing[*]) ne repeat('0',dim(fix_missing)-1);
```

if you might have unknown numbers of array elements (`repeat` takes a character and repeats it n+1 times).

Another useful function, probably not useful here but in the same vein, is `whichn` and `whichc` (numeric/character versions of same thing).  If you wanted to know if ANY of them had a 0 in them:

```
if whichn(0,of fix_missing[*]) > 0;
```

which returns the position of the first zero it finds.

Comment: So, a 0 number will always be turned into '0' as a string and not '0.00' or something of that sort?

Comment: 0 will become `"           0"` by default (which displays badly in comments, thanks markdown, but is eleven spaces plus a zero at the end); `cats` will remove those spaces.  The default number format in SAS is `best12.` in most contexts, which means place the decimal wherever it needs to best display the number - integer if it's an integer, with decimal if decimal, and follow some rules to deal with digits beyond 12 total length.